# I Want to use variable in cucumber feature file

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, calabash

There are scenarios in feature files wherein I've use the text **"Foo"** and on click its open a new page. this text sometime changes to **"Foo1"** or **"Foo2"** or to **something else**. **to avoid line by line change in feature file for "Foo" to "Foo1" or "Foo2"** is there any way that I can globally declare variable in top/bottom of the feature file where I can set the required text in variable on fly and I shall start executing my test instantly?

This change exist in many feature files and around 1000 lines in feature file. To get solution for this, I try on setting environment variables but I couldn't reach all the way till end this issue to solve. So can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What if you do the replacement in your step implementation instead? Then you could have the desired value in a separate file or pass it as arguments. That way you don't need to hard code the values.

Could [scenario outlines](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines) help you in any way or is the value only changing depending on external changes?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was scenario outlines like @homaxto said.

Then I thought you might want to affect it by which system you are connected to. You can do this through configuration. I have done this with [Fig_Newton](https://github.com/cheezy/fig_newton).

You can either set an environment varaible or use one in the commandline. Or you can use [@hook](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/hooks) type tags. With a hook tag, you can have a tag at the top of a feature file that you can use to set a variable that affects how the steps operate (but it needs to be handled inside the step).